# How to convert rows to columns with the frequency of its values in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I convert rows to columns with the frequency of its values in SQL?

For Example: I have the data as shown below:

[image: Input Data]

and the output expecting is:

[image: expected output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With UNION ALL for each fruit:

```
select sum(apple) countofcustomer, 'Apple' Fruits from tablename
union all
select sum(banana), 'Banana' from tablename
union all
select sum(orange), 'Orange' from tablename
union all
select sum(strawberry), 'Strawberry' from tablename
```

Answer (score 3):

I would put the values in columns:

```
select sum(apple) as num_apples,
       sum(banana) as num_bananas,
       sum(orange) as num_oranges,
       sum(strawberry) as num_strawberries
from t;
```

That seems good enough for most purposes.  But, if you want to unpivot it:

```
select f.fruit,
       (case fruit
            when 'apple' then sum(apple),
            when 'banana' then sum(banana)
            when 'orange' then sum(orange) 
            when 'strawberry' then sum(strawberry)
        end) as num
from t cross join
     (select 'apple' as fruit union all
      select 'banana' as fruit union all
      select 'orange' as fruit union all
      select 'strawberry' as fruit
     ) f
group by f.fruit
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, For the first part of the query - How do I categorize it ? So I need those rows to be categorized as Fruits and the count should b transposed as columns with the counts. Your help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @RakshithBasavaraj . . . This answers the question that you asked.  I don't understand your comment.

Comment: I got that, Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

Group by customer and then use SUM to count the units for each column>

```
SELECT 
    customer,
    SUM(apple) AS Apple,
    SUM(banana) AS Banana,
    SUM(orange) AS Orange,
    SUM(strawberry) AS Strawberry
GROUP BY customer
```